# How does Hibernate stores collections?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I would like to know, how does Hibernate stores collections internaly?

To make it clearer. I have entity Text which is annotated by a collection of Tags. So there are two tables one for Texts and another for Tags, what Y want to know is where and how does Hibernate store information about references to all Tags that annotates single Text entity.

Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Tags will have a reference to their parent Text. The query would look something like

```
select * from tags inner join text where tag.textid = text.textid
```

This way, when it sets up the collection, all of the tags for a particular text come out.

Comment: But what if one tag is held by many text entities? I.e tags are unique entities.

Comment: In a many to many situation, typically a linking table is used. This allows SQL or whatever database to maintain the relationships and hibernate simply relies on the mapping to pull the right stuff out of the database.